# For an orientable surface S and a fixed vector v, prove that...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

Prove that
$$2\iint_S v\cdot n dS = \int_{\partial S}(v\times r) dS$$
where $r=(x,y,z)$ and $n$ is the unit normal vector for $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to use Stokes theorem. Basically we want to show that :
$$
rot (v \times r) = 2v
$$
I will write $v = (v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$
$$
v \times r = (-v_3\ y+v_2\ z, v_3\ x-v_1\ z, -v_2\ x+v_1\ y)^T
$$
Then apply the $rot$ operator and remembering that $v$ is constant :
$$
\nabla \times (-v_3\ y+v_2\ z, v_3\ x-v_1\ z, -v_2\ x+v_1\ y)^T \overset{(*)}{=}
(2v_1,2v_2,2v_3)^T
$$
$(*)$ I'll let you do this boring but easy computation !

Putting our result and Stokes together :
$$
\iint_{\Sigma} rot(v \times r) \cdot dn = \int_{\partial\Sigma} 2v\cdot dl
$$

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had to apply Stokes somewhere but I did not know exactly at which point how.

Comment: @Zunzub How do you define the rot operator?

Comment: @JohnDoe [There](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)). TL;DR : Given a field $\textbf{F} = (F_1,F_2,F_3)$ then $rot\ \textbf{F} = \nabla \times \textbf{F}$ where $\nabla = (\partial_x,\ \partial_y,\ \partial_z)$.
You simply apply the vector product between this weird "differential vector" and your vector field and get another vector field !

Comment: @Zubzub Oh okay thanks, not familiar with the notation rot usually use $\nabla \times$.

Comment: @Zubzub What is the vector $r = (x,y,z)$ in the original question, is it a constant vector $\vec{r} = (x,y,z)$ So can it be taken out of the integrand? Or is it the vector that points to the boundary $\partial S$?